# not able to understand __syncthreads()

Tags: c, cuda, parallel-processing, nvidia

The book quotes:

> In CUDA, a `__syncthreads()` statement , if present must be executed by all threads in a block . When a `__syncthreads()` is placed in an `if`statement ,either all threads in a block execute the path that includes the `__syncthreads()`or none of them does . For an `if-then-else` statement , if each path has a `__syncthreads()`statement , either all threads in a block execute the `__syncthreads()` on the `then` path or all of them execute the `else`path . The two `__syncthreads()` are different barrier synchronization points . If a thread in a block executes the `then` path and another executes the `else` path,they would be waiting at different barrier synchronization points . They would end up waiting for each other forever . It is the responsibility of the programmers to write their code so that these requirements are satisfied .

No examples for the `if`and `if-else-then` cases have been given , so I am not able to understand the concept . Please explain me in simple words both the cases .

PS: I am a beginner in parallel programming and CUDA.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's assume you have a kernel that is be launched with one thread block that consists of 32 threads.

`kernel<<<1,32>>>()`

The code of there kernel looks like:

```
__global__ void kernel()
{
  if (threadIdx.x < 16)
  {
    // do something
    __syncthreads();
  }
  else
  {
    // do something
    __snycthreads();
  }
}
```

The first 16 threads of your thread block will run the if statement. The other 16 the else statement. If every of the first 16 threads reach the `__syncthreads`, than they block until the whole thread block reach the statement. But this case will never appear because the other 16 threads stucks in the else branch and there will be a deadlock.

You should avoid to use `__syncthreads` in different if and else branches or you have to be sure that a whole thread block runs in the same branch!

Comment: okay is it like these are two waiting points , the first 16 reach one , the last 16 reach other but these two waiting points dont know of eac other . am i right in thinking so

Comment: Yes you can express it in that way. The first 16 have no way how to reach the other `__syncthreads` to forfill the statement.